# How to return the corresponding image by id in a helper with CollectionFS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, collections

I had real problems writing the title of this question. I am using gridfs for my storage, so the files are stored in my MongoDb. Now I have the following situation:

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS('images', {});

Images = new FS.Collection('images', {
    stores: [imageStore]
});

Test = new Meteor.Collection('test');
```

The Images are stored in Images and the "posts" are stored in `test`. Now when I upload an image, as I can't reference the image in my Test collection, I save the `._id` for that image.

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file)
{
    var image = Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj)
        {

        });
    Test.insert({name: 'Test!', userId: '123123', image: image._id});
});
```

Now in my template, I want to show the name and the image. But what do I return in my helper? My template for a single post looks like this:

```
<li>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <img src="{{file.url}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" />
</li>
```

And the Helper function:

```
Tests: function ()
{
    return each-test-with-their-image;
}
```

I imagined something like this, but it looks stupid as hell:

```
Tests: function ()
{
    var tests = Test.find().fetch();
    for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++)
    {
        tests[i].file = Images.findOne({_id: tests[i].image});
    }
    return tests;
}
```

But I feel that there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterate over an array of results you can just get the url in a helper as each document is displayed. This is cleaner and you don't have to recompute the whole array as docs are added/removed/changed.

html:

```
<li>
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  <img src="{{url}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" />
</li>
```

js:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  url: function(){ 
    var queryImage = Images.findOne({_id: this.image});
    return queryImage && queryImage.url();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan - was being lazy ;)

Comment: Why the hell didn't I think of that... Thank you, sir!

Comment: I have one question about that now that I think about it if I may. How does "this" know the right context?

Comment: `this` in a template helper receives the data context of the *template* itself. Meteor does that for you.

Comment: The cool thing is, that this is a child template of the template that "receives" the data. So I guess "this" even travels up the templates until it finds one with data context... Mind blown, thanks